# Blank Screen when adding a moodle (3.1.7) activity to a course

Tags: php, linux, mariadb, moodle, rhel

I have installed a LAMP with PHP 5.4.16, Maria DB and Moodle 3.1.7 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.

I installed it with

```
sudo yum install moodle
```

When i am pressing the Button "Add an activity or ressource", the popup opens to select the activity/ressource, but when i click the "Add"-Button i get a blank screen (Chrome says HTTP 500).

When i turn debugging on i get this:

```
...moodle/course/modedit.php?add=folder&type=&course=2§ion=0&return=0&sr=0 Fatal error: Call to undefined method tool_lp_course_competencies_form_element::tool_lp_course_competencies_form_element() inÂ /usr/share/pear/HTML/QuickForm/element.phpÂ on lineÂ 375
```

I did not change any source code. What can be the origin of this?

With best regards,
Bjoern

Comment: Have you tried purging the caches? Although that shouldn't be needed. Visit `/admin/purgecaches.php`.

Answer (score 0):

When i turn on Debugging i get the following error:
...moodle/course/modedit.php?add=folder&type=&course=2§ion=0&return=0&sr=0 Fatal error: Call to undefined method tool_lp_course_competencies_form_element::tool_lp_course_competencies_form_element() inÂ /usr/share/pear/HTML/QuickForm/element.phpÂ on lineÂ 375

My (weak) Solution:
When i turn off the Competencies under 
Administration -> Site Administration -> Competencies -> Competencies Settings -> Enable competencies 
it works. 
If someone has a better solution please tell me.